# Add dashed border to bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, border, android-bitmap

I'm trying to add a dashed border to `bitmap`, using the code below I'm able to add a dashed border to only `ImageView`, How I can add it to `bitmap` too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="1dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="8px"
                android:color="#fff"
                android:dashWidth="30px"
                android:dashGap="30px" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I want something like that :

[image]

Comment: So you want to change the bitmap showed inside the ImageView to contain a dashed border? I suggest you to clarify this point.

Comment: @Ivan what I want is add a dashed line border to my `bitmap`

Comment: Why don't you add a view of dashed background over image

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to use canvas, you can create a canvas object from your bitmap. Like that `Canvas canvas = new Canvas(yourBitmap)`. Then you can draw on the canvas at the end all drawing operations are applied on your bitmap.